# What are the correct type annotations for a function to find prime numbers using square root?

Tags: haskell

In order to improve the execution time checking whether a number is prime, I am trying to use a comprehension list up to the square root of n. When running the code, it's throwing errors related to not specifying a variable type (That I more less get but failed to fix). The initial advice I got was to have an Integer type as input and a Bool as output. However, I was trying to have a 'helper' function to get all the factors and then have the isPrime function to check whether n was prime.

This is the line of code:

```
isPrime n = [x | x <- [2..sqrt n], n `mod` x == 0]
```

This is the error after running the previous line

```
isPrime 100
<interactive>:12:1: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        ...plus 22 others
```

Comment: `sqrt` works on floating point types, only, while `mod` works on integral types. You can't use both on `n`. You probably need some conversion like `[2..floor(sqrt (fromIntegral n :: Double))]` instead. Also, the name `isPrime` sounds like it's returning a boolean instead of a list of divisors.

Comment: You are right, the function is supposed to return a Bool. I was trying to implement it in two different functions and I forgot to change the name.

Comment: Also, thanks for the comment. As a matter of fact, the conversion you are advising is what I have been also told to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [**`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) requires the type of `n` to be an instance of `Floating` whereas [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) requires it to be `Integral`.

While technically speaking one *can* make a type that is both a member of the `Floating` and `Integral` type class, it does not make much sense, since `Integral` requires the type to span a set of *integral* numbers and should be convertable to an `Integer`, whereas `Floating` means it should be able to capture the results of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions like `sqrt`, `sin`, etc.

An easy fix is to make a function that calculates the integral square root, for example:

```
isqrt :: Integral a => a -> a
isqrt = ceiling . (sqrt :: Double -> Double) . fromIntegral
```

and then use this with:

```
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> [a]
isPrime n = [x | x <- [2..isqrt n], n `mod` x == 0]
```

For `100` we get the following dividers:

```
Prelude> isPrime 100
[2,4,5,10]
```

Here our `isqrt` might still be sensitive to rounding errors, so it might be better to implement an algorithm that will do all the work in integer land. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: “it does not make much sense” – specifically, `Integral` types must be convertible to `Integer`, whereas `Floating` types must be able to _capture the results_ of `sqrt` etc.. That's what makes the classes in every sensible way mutually exclusive.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, that is a better wording. I updated the section based on the comment.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. Will try to keep everything in Integers type.